# animation on pressing back button

Tags: android

I have added the following code to my activity and got the desired animation, but pressing the back button the animation is not the same I.e the activity just closes normally. How can I add animation when back button is pressed

```
public void notesAndCodeClick(View v){

    Intent notesIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, NotesActivity.class);
    ActivityOptions notesoptions = ActivityOptions.makeScaleUpAnimation(v, 0, 0, v.getWidth(), v.getHeight());
    startActivity(notesIntent, notesoptions.toBundle());
}
```

Comment: overridePendingTransition(animation from anim resource folder)

Answer (score 8):

Try this,

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onBackPressed();
        this.overridePendingTransition(R.anim.trans_right_in,
                R.anim.trans_right_out);
    }
```

Add both the files listed below to your anim folder

> **res --> anim**

**trans_right_in.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <translate
        android:duration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime"
        android:fromXDelta="-100%p"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"
        android:toXDelta="0" />

</set>
```

**trans_right_out.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <translate
        android:duration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime"
        android:fromXDelta="0"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"
        android:toXDelta="100%p" />

</set>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can set IN and OUT animation for Activity while pressing back button.

**Left to Right animation :**

Put this file in **res/anim/left_to_right.xml** :-

```
 <set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         android:shareInterpolator="false">
      <translate android:fromXDelta="-100%" android:toXDelta="0%"
                 android:fromYDelta="0%" android:toYDelta="0%"
                 android:duration="700"/>
    </set>
```

**Right to Left animation :**

Put this file in **res/anim/right_to_left.xml** :-

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:shareInterpolator="false">
  <translate
     android:fromXDelta="0%" android:toXDelta="100%"
     android:fromYDelta="0%" android:toYDelta="0%"
     android:duration="700" />
</set>
```

**Now in onBackPressed() : -**

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.right_to_left, R.anim.left_to_right);   
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to just do one thing, call **animation after finishing your activity** like this.

```
finish();
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.nothing,R.anim.nothing);
```

Happy Coding....

Answer (score 1):

To add an animation when the back button is pressed, you can use the onBackPressed () method of the Activity class.

**Example**

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    // add your animation   
}
```

**Android documentation**

> ***public void onBackPressed ():***
>   Called when the activity has detected the user's press of the back key. The default implementation simply finishes the current activity, but you can override this to do whatever you want.